# Counts the frequency of each character using the dictionary python 3.8

Tags: python

I have to write a Python program that takes a string as an input from the user and
I have this string:
`Python programming is fun`

I want to count the frequency of each character using the dictionary which should be:
`{'p': 2, 'y': 1, 't': 1, 'h': 1, 'o': 2, 'n': 3, 'r': 2, 'g': 2, 'a': 1, 'm': 2, 'i': 2, 's': 1, 'f': 1, 'u': 1}`

I tried this:

```
string = input("Enter a string: ")
new_dict = {} #new_dict for frequency
lower_case = string.lower()

for key in lower_case:
    if key in new_dict.keys():
        new_dict[key] = new_dict[key] + 1
    else:
        new_dict[key] = 1
        
print(new_dict)
```

and the output came:

```
{'p': 2, 'y': 1, 't': 1, 'h': 1, 'o': 2, 'n': 3, ' ': 3, 'r': 2, 'g': 2, 'a': 1, 'm': 2, 'i': 2, 's': 1, 'f': 1, 'u': 1}
```

Here output is counting the spaces in the line. I want to remove the space from the output. What should I apply?

Comment: Just delete the key: `del new_dict[' ']`

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the character is a space, and if it is return to top of the loop

```
string = input("Enter a string: ") 
new_dict = {} #new_dict for frequency 
lower_case = string.lower()

for key in lower_case:
    if key == " ":
        continue  # return to top of loop
    if key in new_dict.keys():
        new_dict[key] = new_dict[key] + 1 
    else: 
        new_dict[key] = 1

print(new_dict)
```

Or just remove the key after counter all characters (including spaces) by doing `new_dict.pop(" ")` after the loop.

Comment: OH Yes!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the spaces from input_string, like

```
string = #input("Enter a string: ")
new_dict = {} #new_dict for frequency
lower_case = string.lower().replace(' ', '')

for key in lower_case:
    if key in new_dict.keys():
        new_dict[key] = new_dict[key] + 1
    else:
        new_dict[key] = 1
        
print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `string.replace(' ', '')` and delete the spaces from the string.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the white-space at the very beginning:

```
string = input("Enter a string: ").replace(' ', '')
new_dict = {}  # new_dict for frequency
lower_case = string.lower()

for key in lower_case:
    if key in new_dict.keys():
        new_dict[key] = new_dict[key] + 1
    else:
        new_dict[key] = 1
print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace()` to remove the spaces.  You can use `defaultdict` to make the code more concise:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

string = input("Enter a string: ").lower().replace(" ", "")
new_dict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for key in string:
    new_dict[key] += 1
```